# Angularjs + nodejs + mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, angularjs

having problem in mobile view no data receive in angularjs..
desktop view is working great.. what's the best solution for this
sorry not good in english.........................................
..................................................................

```
PHP file

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="fcontrol">


<div ng-repeat="person in people">
{{person.fname}}
{{person.lname}}
{{person.email}}
{{person.address}}

</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/control.js"></script>

</body>



Angularjs(control.js)

angular.module("app" , []);

function fcontrol($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("http://localhost:8000/users")
      .success(function(data) {
       $scope.people = data;

     })


}



Nodejs

app.get('/users', function(req, res) {

      var s = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_user order by fname';

      dbconn.query(s, function(err, rows, fields) {
         var row = [];

         if (err) throw err;
           //console.log(rows)
           res.send(rows);
           res.end();
      });


  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try chaging your http get url in angular JS code to YOUR IP:8000/users.(Replace localhost with your system IP).
Also make sure your mobile and PC should connected to same network.(If your IP is not public)

```
Angularjs(control.js)

angular.module("app" , []);

function fcontrol($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("http://<your ip>:8000/users")
      .success(function(data) {
       $scope.people = data;

     })


}
```

Comment: thank you for the response...i forgot angularjs is client side..thanks again